# ON DUPLICATE KEY revert values to DEFAULT

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with a primary/duplicate key - id (not autoincremented) with ~8 columns with default values for all.

```
+-------+----+------+
| id    |Col1| Col2 |
+-------+----+------+
| 1     | A  | B    | 
+-------+----+------+
```

When an INSERT with (id) is performed, and id is already present, I want to revert Col1 and Col2 back to the default values.

So far I managed:

```
INSERT INTO table (id) 
    VALUES (1) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
         Col1 = DEFAULT(Col1), Col2 = DEFAULT(Col2);
```

which I think should work.

1. Can this be achieved with triggers instead? (If so, how?)
2. Is there a keyword to automatically do this on all columns without writing them out? ,e.g. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ALL COLUMNS = DEFAULT(ALL COLUMNS)`?

Edit: Sorry for stating the question "misleading"

Comment: Yes. This seems like a correct way to do it. And, [it works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f74fb563d7eeecbb7e9c77d40c8d741). What is your question?

Comment: @GMB Sorry for stating the question wrong. I will rewrite into two seperate questions: 1.) Is it possible to do this with triggers? If so, what would the trigger look like? 2.) Instead of doing Col1 = DEFAULT(Col1),... can I do ALL COLUMNS = DEFAULT(ALL COLUMNS) ? (i'm missing a keyword here i guess)

Comment: As far as I see, you will have to enumerate the columns, one way or another (either in the query or in the trigger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you just want

```
REPLACE INTO table (id) 
VALUES (1)
```

Comment: thank you! I'm still learning and this did the trick. Never heard of REPLACE before :)